# What is the property called that says that $a^x = a^y$ iff $x = y$?

Tags: exponentiation

I was just wondering why two numbers $a^x$ and $a^y$ are equal only if $x = y$ ? Which power-law is this?

Comment: Just bear in mind that $a=0,\pm 1$ break this rule...

Comment: It's not a power law, it is *injectivity* of the function $f(x) = a^x$ (for $a$ positive and $\neq 1$).

Comment: ah thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true only if $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$ and , in this case, it is a consequence of the fact that the function   $y:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \quad y=a^x$  ,is one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

This is general property of injective function: $$f(x)=f(y)\Longrightarrow x=y$$
In this case your function is the exponent function $f(x)=a^x$, $(a\ne 1, a>0)$

Comment: Wow!! I didn't thought of that. Because i looked at $a^x$ only as a number. Now I see, thank you.

Comment: If you think that this answer in useful for you than you can accept the answer by clicking on  $\surd$.